# Recursive flood fill to find max area of shape in 2D array

Tags: c, recursion, flood-fill

It is required to find the maximum area of the figure. A figure is a group of cells that has a shared side (1 means that the cell is filled in, 0 - empty).

INPUT:

```
6 10 // array size
1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0
0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0
0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

OUTPUT:

```
12 (The maximum area of a figure consisting of ones)
```

Comment: A way out of the maze *from where*? And the code does not compute or output the maximum area of `1` characters, only a boolean result.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @WeatherVane way out from top left to down right cell. And yeah, of course the example do not compute area, because this code for other task but with such algorithm. In code example I am just asking question: is there way out from top left to down right cell in given matrix? The main reason of this publication: I can't really understand how I should use flood fill algorithm to compute max area.

Comment: If a `1` is a wall, there isn't a route from top left to bottom right, and the code reports "Doesn't exist". It's a trivial case where the origin itself can't be entered, and no recursion occurs anyway. Are you asking: how can I adapt the code to find the largest wall area? By traversing the grid and for each `1` cell that has not been filled, do a floodfill which returns the count of the cells filled.

Comment: @WeatherVane ok, I will try your idea, sorry for such snafu question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code in C to solve my problem by recursive FloodFill algorithm was

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX(a, b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))

int countArea(int x, int y, int **matrix, int n, int m)
{
    if (x >= n || x < 0 || y >= m || y < 0)
        return 0;
    if (matrix[x][y] != 1)
        return 0;
    matrix[x][y] = 2;
    return (1 + countArea(x + 1, y, matrix, n, m) + countArea(x - 1, y, matrix, n, m)
             + countArea(x, y + 1, matrix, n, m) + countArea(x, y - 1, matrix, n, m));
}

int main() 
{
  int n, m;
  scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);
  int **matrix = malloc(sizeof(int*) * n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      matrix[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * m);
      for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
          scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);
      }
  }
  int max_area = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
          if (matrix[i][j] == 1) {
              int area = countArea(i, j, matrix, n, m);
              max_area = MAX(max_area, area);
          }
      }
  }
  printf("%d", max_area);
  return 0;
}
```